# Were is the CKEDITOR Text Shadow Plugin?

Tags: ckeditor

I have absolutely no idea where else to post this and I'm certain this isn't the place but I want to know when there will be a free and reliable text-shadow plugin for CKEDITOR?

I think browser compatibility is good enough for 'text-shadow' style and for an official plugin that adds and removes text shadows.

Hoping someone that can do something finds this and thinks about it...

Answer (score 0):

You can find this plugin for ckEditor. http://ckeditor.com/download

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin I'm describing doesn't exist.